# Testing on Edge 13

Tags: cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Is there a way to test a website on Edge 13? I have a particular bug that only seems to be occurring in it.

I can do 14+ via BrowserStack and crossbrowsertesting.com but neither do 13.

I also have Virtual Box , but downloading that means it is already at Edge 17 (i.e. can't install original Win 10 + Edge 13 and prevent updates).

Any ideas greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

At present, We can only install and use the latest version of the MS Edge.

You said the bug can be reproduce on Edge 13, but you did not inform us which kind of bug.

New versions comes with improvements and new features. As you said you are not able to produce the bug in any other version of Edge, Which means bug is solved now.

If bug is not reproducible then, May i know whats your issue here?

If you just want to make a test with Edge 13 then I did not get any way to make a test with that specific version.

It is always advisable to use the latest version of any application.

Comment: Perhaps I could have been clearer. We are seeing a JavaScript issue via Rollbar on Edge 13 only and in order to attempt to fix the issue, I would like to replicate it locally so that I know when it's fixed.

Comment: I can understand your requirement for Edge 13 but I did not get anyway to install Edge 13 when i try to search.